# Open rasters in ESRI .gdb format with QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I got a .gdb file (v. 10 and v. 10.5) that include rasters. I don't have any ESRI tools and would like to open the rasters in QGIS v. 3.10. Is there any way to extract the rasters from the .gdb file and import them in QGIS? To drag the file into the layer panel doesn't work. Perhaps a workaround through another open source software?

Comment: No not possible currently. If you can compile C++ have a look at https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue

Comment: ok, thanks for the link! For now I will ask to send me the data again in tiff format but for future tasks I will definitly also have a look at the method described in the link.